# Replacing WooCommerce product Image using ACF custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to replace the  Image on WooCommerce Shop Page using hooks and advanced custom fields, but there something that I can not achieve:

- The image I’m trying to evoke in my shop page is an image which I put in my custom content-single-product.php template, using ACF.
- Here bellow is a copy of the code I used in my `content-single-product.php` to introduce the image 'prod_hero_second', that works, which I would like to use as a thumbnail in my shop page:

  ```
  <?php 
  $image = get_field('prod_hero_second');
  if( !empty( $image ) ): ?>
      <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" 
  if( $image ): ?>
  <p class="hero-caption"><?php echo esc_html($image['caption']); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
  ```

How can I evoke this ACF `prod_hero_second` image into my shop page?

I tried to put the following code on my function.php but it does not work at all, no images appear on my shop page:

```
function replacing_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    // Remove product images from the shop loop
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
    // Adding something instead
    function wc_template_loop_product_replaced_thumb() {
        $image-> get_field ('prod_hero_second');
        echo $image;
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'wc_template_loop_product_replaced_thumb', 10 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'replacing_template_loop_product_thumbnail');
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What output do you get for if you replace `$image-> get_field ('prod_hero_second');` and 'echo $image' by `echo '<pre>' . print_r( get_field ('prod_hero_second'), true ) . '</pre>';` ?

Comment: Hi [@LoicTheAztec][1]
  [1]: http://@LoicTheAztec 
I get the <a> link with inside the full array text of the image, something like this: <pre>Array ( [ID] => [id] => [title] => [filename] => [filesize] => [url] => https:// [link] => https:// [alt] => [author] => 1 [description] => [caption] => [name] => [status] => inherit [uploaded_to] => 297 [date] => 2020-05-16 12:43:31 [modified] => 2020-05-16 12:43:31 [menu_order] => 0 [mime_type] => image/jpeg [type] => image ETC...ETC... ) ) </pre>

Comment: Hi guys, were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that I solved the issue.
My goal was to override the WooCommerce product image that is used by default in the shop page, used in the product 'grids, and which size is defined as woocommerce_thumbnail 
My aim was to use a different image from my custom single-product.php template, the image named as field ’prod_hero_second’.

I found that this code works in my functions.php in order to override the default product image and use my custom ’prod_hero_second’ image as a woocommerce_thumbnail:

```
echo '<img src="'.get_field('prod_hero_second', $product_id)['url'].'" class="woocommerce_thumbnail">';
```

I'm not so skilled to evaluate if this code is the most correct and effective, but I hope it can come as a valid solution.